# How can I display the object property in text format inside the another index.html webpage in Javascript instead of an URL?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

> Below there is a function I wrote to get Movies images and I hyperlinked those images with the Trending_movie.overview property. 
> When I click on the image I get the below-mentioned error ,the Function is converting the property Trending_movie.overview into somekind of URL
>
> > The Error is :-
> > Cannot GET /A%20group%20of%20vigilantes%20known%20informally%20as%20%E2%80%9CThe%20Boys%E2%80%9D%20set%20out%20to%20take%20down%20corrupt%20superheroes%20with%20no%20more%20than%20blue-collar%20grit%20and%20a%20willingness%20to%20fight%20dirty.

```
function getTrendingMovies(Trending_movies){
    const trending = document.createElement('div')
    trending.setAttribute('class','All_trending_movies')
    Trending_movies.map((Trending_movie)=>{
        const img =document.createElement('img');
        const a= document.createElement('a');
         a.setAttribute('href',Trending_movie.overview);
        img.src=image_url + Trending_movie.backdrop_path;
         a.appendChild(img);
         trending.appendChild(a);
        });  
        
    return trending;
    }
```

> The Object is given below:-

```
Trending_movies:
backdrop_path: "/mGVrXeIjyecj6TKmwPVpHlscEmw.jpg"
first_air_date: "2019-07-25"
genre_ids: (2) [10759, 10765]
id: 76479
media_type: "tv"
name: "The Boys"
origin_country: ["US"]
original_language: "en"
original_name: "The Boys"
overview: "A group of vigilantes known informally as “The Boys” set out to take down corrupt superheroes with no more than blue-collar grit and a willingness to fight dirty."
popularity: 1707.804
poster_path: "/mY7SeH4HFFxW1hiI6cWuwCRKptN.jpg"
vote_average: 8.4
vote_count: 2162
```

> I want to display the overview property on the new webpage in the text format instead of the URL.
>
> Any kind of help would be appreciated...

Comment: What are you creating an `<a>` tag for?

Comment: You are trying to set an overview description as an anchor link path.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I have created <a> tag so that when I click on the image a new webpage can open for eg: index2.html and I can display there the overview of the movie on that index2.html webpage, I can't find the solution to do that...Please help if you know how to do that :) Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `overview` property to the `href` value of the anchor element. Then set the `href` to your `index2.html` and add `?id=` after it. The value after the `=` should be the `id` of the `Trending_movie`.

```
function getTrendingMovies(Trending_movies){
  const trending = document.createElement('div')
  trending.classList.add('All_trending_movies')
  Trending_movies.map((Trending_movie)=>{
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    img.src = image_url + Trending_movie.backdrop_path;
    a.appendChild(img);
    a.textContent = Trending_movie.overview;
    a.href = `index2.html?id=${Trending_movie.id}`
    trending.appendChild(a);
  });  
  return trending;
}
```

Then on your index2.html you get the id of the movie that you want to show from the URL. There create a new script file where you will read the `id` and loop through your Trending movies.

The [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method on the trending movies array will help you retrieve a single object from the array that matches the id.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search); // Parses the URL
const id = params.get('id'); // Gets the ID from the URL.

/**
 * Function that loops through the trending movies
 * and returns the trending movie object that has
 * the same ID as is passed through the second param.
 * Or returns undefined when it is not found.
 */
function getTrendingMovieById(trendingMovies, id) {
  return trendingMovies.find(movie => {
    return movie.id === id
  });
}

// Now you get the trending movie you are looking for by id.
const trendingMovie = getTrendingMovieById(Trending_movies, id);

// Then check if it is found, if not stop the script.
if (trendingMovie === undefined) {
  return;
}

// Now you can do stuff with your single trending movie.
console.log(trendingMovie);
```

Comment: I am getting the id of the movie on index2.html but am I not getting how and where to use const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search); const id = params.get('id'); and how can I loop through the trending movies. Do I have to write the above code in the index2.html script tag? or inside the same script.js file function getTrendingMovies or outside the function. –

Comment: The `index2.html` file should have it's own script with the code I've added from the second example, combined with the `Trending_movies` array, because you do need your data to show something on the page.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I really appreciate your help... My problem solved successfully.

Comment: I just added my piece of code to Map over trending_movies given below:-  
        function getTrendingInfo(trendingMovies){
        const trending_Info =document.createElement('div');
         trending_Info.setAttribute('class','des');
      {
                trending_Info_template = 
                trendingMovies.map((movie)=>{
                    if (id == movie.id)
                    return `<h2>${movie.overview}</h2>`
                });
            }
            trending_Info.innerHTML=  trending_Info_template
            return trending_Info;
        }

Comment: Nice! Make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out.